# Terminator (Ubuntu) like app for OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm using Ubuntu on a daily basis, and recently (6 months ago) I bought a Mac, so the first thing I did was installing VMWare and Ubuntu on my MBP.

I'm a developer and a huge fan of [Terminator](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/terminator/). With Terminator, you can open multiple file in one window, code separatly on them, and many other great things.

I thought that if it runs on Ubuntu it could possibly run on Mac OSX but it seems that it doesn't work.

Is there a Terminator-like terminal app for OS X Yosemite?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use [iTerm2](http://iterm2.com). Can do most things that Terminator does.

Comment: +1 for iTerm2 - it's currently best terminal emulator for mac imho. And it can do almost - if not all - that Terminator does.

Comment: There are not so many choices for terminal emulators on OS X...

Comment: There are several choices for terminals. No emulators required!

Comment: iTerm is extremely slow comparing to other terminals, like macTerm.

Comment: Can you open multiple ssh sessions and write in all of the them at the same time? This is for me the main feature I need from Terminator

Comment: @CarlosVerdes You can do it in iTerm2. There is something called `Broadcast Input` in Iterm. Have a look.

Comment: @NabarunChatterjee tx!

Comment: How do I continue my ssh session after spliting the pane. If i have already logged in to ssh to my server and I when i split pane i should be in continued in the opened session. Is it possible ? I am desperate about it.

Comment: @indianwebdevil if I remember correctly you can't do that in terminator either.

Answer (score 11):

There is hope in brew too:

```
$ brew search terminator
homebrew/x11/terminator
```

Here I would like to say too that, agreed ITerm2 is great but there might be use cases where terminator ... I mean the same terminator on Linux would shine such as better keyboard mappings for `emacs` out of the box or similar.

Comment: unfortunately the terminator ui is bit-ugly on OS X. I guess Thats because the pygtk stuff that powers the UI is not themed well for OS X.

Comment: It also doesn't install as an app, so launching it is a bit of a pain. And it brings along a bundle of dependencies you might not otherwise use (making clean-up an issue if you decide to remove it)

Answer (score 6):

My solution to darting between Mac and Linux as a developer is to use `tmux`, which runs in the terminal on both platforms. You get an identical feature set, and you can even sync your config files between the two platforms for all your fave build shortcuts across terminal panes, and anything else you'll ever think of, I imagine.

`tmux` runs in a terminal, and from there you can divide up the terminal window as desired.

`tmux` runs in a terminal, so it's not sexy.

Comment: You have an extra not in the last sentence ; - )

Answer (score 4):

The gnometerminator docs are slightly outdated. Fink is now in stable, but must be installed from source on OSX 10.11.

http://pdb.finkproject.org/pdb/package.php/terminator?rel_id=10.11-x86_64-current-stable

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to do run Terminator with Fink:

> To install Terminator on Mac OS X you will need to be using
>   the Fink project, and have it configured to allow unstable software.
>   With those requirements satisfied, in a terminal run: fink install
>   terminator

http://gnometerminator.blogspot.no/p/introduction.html

Although iTerm2 works great for me (although I prefer Yakuake for terminal on Linux)

Answer (score 2):

While not completely 1:1 with all of the features of Terminator, [Hyper](https://hyper.is/) is a nice looking terminal on macOS that is easily extensible. I use multiple window panes frequently and Hyper does a great job at that.

If you have a really busy terminal (and I mean REALLY busy, like spewing data) it's a bit slower since it's backed in web tech. Still, it's an option worth looking at.

Answer (score 1):

it's a bit late, but for anyone reading this, use [warp](https://www.warp.dev/)

this one is amazing

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).