# Terminator terminal on Mac

Tags: terminal

I installed terminator using these instructions:

https://jee-appy.blogspot.com/2017/10/install-terminator-mac.html

Then I started it up with the `terminator` command from the terminal.  Terminator comes up, but I don't see a shell prompt.  When I use it on Ubuntu I'm able to to see the shell prompt and type.

Comment: I'm curious if you're aware of iterm2 as an option? It has all the features of Terminator but is native to macOS. I'm a long-term Linux user whose has to use macOS for work so am used to using Terminator as well. - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/156151/terminator-ubuntu-like-app-for-os-x-yosemite.